# Modify a solution to not load projects from outside of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If I open a solution, unload a project then reopen the solution visual studio remembers not to not load the project again.

How can I do this outside of visual studio? Which file is this setting stored in?

Visual Studio's annoying conversion wizard won't let me open the solution without converting all the projects, I have already converted the ones I want to work with and want to set the other ones to be unloaded so I am not prompted to convert them.

[edit] As an alternative as the SUO file contains this information which I cannot edit, is there a way to tell visual studio to open a solution but to not load any of the projects? This would be quite useful to know anyway, to quickly open a large solution with many projects.

Comment: Why don't you simply delete from the solution the projects you don't want to use?

Comment: Eventually we do want to convert the other projects, but it will be up to another team to do them. Plus I have a feeling removing projects from the solution would worry some people, even if they could just be added back in later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its in the Solution User Options file (.suo) which is binary. So you likely won't find an easy way to set it there.